# phpunit test class which extends another class

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit, automated-tests

I'm new to phpunit (and any other test driven development).
I've setup phpunit using composer and so far everything is alright.

I'm trying to following their tutorial which can be found here:
https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Here comes my problem:
I have a class which looks like this:

```
class MyClassName
    extends CoreClass
    implements ClassName
```

In their example they do it like this:

```
class MyClassName
    extends TestCase
```

But that won't work for me since I have to extend another class as well.
How does this work?

I want to test `MyClassName` only, I haven't build the core so I want to stay out of there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you called you class `MyClassName`, the test class should be called `MyClassNameTest` (notice the `Test` suffix).

Depending on the namespace you want to use (and configured in composer), your class will live somewhere in the `src` directory, i.e. `src/MyClassName.php`:

```php
<?php

class MyClassName extends CoreClass implements ClassName
{
}
```

Your test cases will live in the `tests` directory, i.e. `tests/MyClassNameTest.php`:

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyClassNameTest extends TestCase
{
}
```

The most popular approach is to mirror the `src` directory in `tests`.